# Switch between Solr and DB for Query Execution alfresco cmis

Tags: solr, alfresco, alfresco-share, cmis

Using Alfresco Community - 5.0.0 version.

Tried below properties in alfresco-global.properties file:

**queryConsistency=EVENTUAL** then all queries are going to Solr.
**queryConsistency=TRANSACTIONAL** then all queries are going to DB.
And **Default mode** executes all queries from DB first then Solr in case of failure from DB.

**Q1: Is there any mode by which I can query Solr first and if there are no results from Solr then query DB in one transaction?**

**Q2: Can we execute some queries from Solr and some from DB from JAVA side?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Alfresco calls this a [*Transactional Metadata Query*](https://docs.alfresco.com/5.0/concepts/intrans-metadata-feature.html), where the query can fall back to the database when Solr returns no results.

Details on configuring this behavior can be found [here](https://docs.alfresco.com/5.0/concepts/intrans-metadata-configure.html), but basically `queryConsistency` should be set to **TRANSACTIONAL_IF_POSSIBLE**.

It's important to note, especially if you're converting Lucene queries to CMIS, that certain query parameters (e.g., `+PATH:`) and wildcards (e.g., `@docs:pageId:homepage`) require Solr to function, and cannot refer to the database directly in the event of a Solr failure. You can test whether a given parameter requires Solr in Alfresco under Admin Tools / Node Browser. Run your query selecting different types; `type: solr-fts-alfresco` is Solr-only; `type: db-afts` to query Solr first and fallback to the database if Solr returns nothing.

And to answer your second question, the second link above mentions:

> The `solr.query.cmis.queryConsistency` and `solr.query.fts.queryConsistency` properties can also be set per query on the SearchParameters and QueryOptions objects.

So it seems you can accomplish what you want within your Java code, but I have not tried this myself. I find it most desirable, as a general rule, to hit Solr first for its performance gains then fallback to the database only if necessary. I can't think of a good case for embedding the data source selection within your business logic.

Comment: The type `fts-alfresco` is **NOT** SOLR-only. It is the type used for the DbOrIndexSwitchingQueryLanguage and as such will cause the query consistency handling to be used. The type `solr-fts-alfresco` would be SOLR-only. But anyway, you should **never** rely on this type or `db-afts` since these are technical languages. Instead of specifying these in your queries called from custom code, use the `queryConsistency` runtime parameter that you can pass via the SearchParameters class to restrict to EVENTUAL and TRANSACTIONAL for achieving SOLR-first and fallback to DB.

Comment: Thanks, Axel. I've corrected the `fts-alfresco` reference to `solr-fts-alfresco` (and when I have time, I'll check these scenarios and update my answer further if necessary). I agree you shouldn't rely on these; I hope I made that clear in my last paragraph. I mention them only as a method of checking queries in the Node Browser.